# How can I link User ID from Firebase Auth to UserID from Firestore in Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

when my user sign up, he puts his email, username and password. The email and password are stored in the Firebase Auth database. So an Id is created and associated for this user. (kmupeDXnfEYnhbdpkvLUoFbIjnb2 for exemple). Now I want to create an user profile (profile pic, username, etc..). For that I have to create a Firestore collection and document with the username and the ID linked to the firebase auth (kmupeDXnfEYnhbdpkvLUoFbIjnb2). I have no idea how to do that can someone help me ? Thanks a lot !
[image]

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_dev/reusable.dart';
import 'package:flutter_dev/home.dart';

class SignUp extends StatefulWidget {
  const SignUp({super.key});

  @override
  State<SignUp> createState() => _SignUpState();
}

class _SignUpState extends State<SignUp> {
  final TextEditingController _passwordTextController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _emailTextController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _userNameTextController = TextEditingController();


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        elevation: 0,
        title: const Text('Sign Up'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            reusableTextField("Enter Username", Icons.person_outline, false,
                _userNameTextController, context),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            reusableTextField("Enter Email ID", Icons.email_outlined, false,
                _emailTextController, context),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            reusableTextField("Enter Password", Icons.lock_outline, true,
                _passwordTextController, context),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            signInsignUpButton(context, false, () {

             final db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

              db.collection("users").doc("uid").set({
                'fullName': _userNameTextController,
                'email': _emailTextController,
                'accountCreated': Timestamp.now(),
              }).onError((e, _) => print("Error writing document: $e"));

              FirebaseAuth.instance
                  .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                      email: _emailTextController.text,
                      password: _passwordTextController.text)
                  .then((value) {
                print("Created New Account");
                Navigator.pushReplacement(context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const Home()));
              }).onError((error, stackTrace) {
                print("Error ${error.toString()}");
              });
            }),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Couldn't you move `db.collection("users").doc("uid").set({` within `FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(` callback and change it to `db.collection("users").doc("uid/${value.user.uid}").set({`?

Comment: I don't understand the final code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this would do what you want:

```dart
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_dev/reusable.dart';
import 'package:flutter_dev/home.dart';

class SignUp extends StatefulWidget {
  const SignUp({super.key});

  @override
  State<SignUp> createState() => _SignUpState();
}

class _SignUpState extends State<SignUp> {
  final TextEditingController _passwordTextController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _emailTextController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _userNameTextController = TextEditingController();


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        elevation: 0,
        title: const Text('Sign Up'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            reusableTextField("Enter Username", Icons.person_outline, false,
                _userNameTextController, context),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            reusableTextField("Enter Email ID", Icons.email_outlined, false,
                _emailTextController, context),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            reusableTextField("Enter Password", Icons.lock_outline, true,
                _passwordTextController, context),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            signInsignUpButton(context, false, () {
              FirebaseAuth.instance
                  .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                      email: _emailTextController.text,
                      password: _passwordTextController.text)
                  .then((value) {
                final db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

                db.collection("users").doc("uid/${value.user.uid}").set({
                  'fullName': _userNameTextController.text,
                  'email': _emailTextController.text,
                  'accountCreated': Timestamp.now(),
                }).onError((e, _) => print("Error writing document: $e"));
                print("Created New Account");
                Navigator.pushReplacement(context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const Home()));
              }).onError((error, stackTrace) {
                print("Error ${error.toString()}");
              });
            }),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The `FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(` callback is of type [`UserCredential`](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase/latest/firebase/UserCredential-class.html). You can access the `uid` via this `UserCredential`: `value.user.uid`

Comment: It as an error on the .uid : The property 'uid' can't be unconditionally accessed because the receiver can be 'null'.
Try making the access conditional (using '?.') or adding a null check to the target ('!').

Comment: I replace by value.user?.uid and now the simulator is crashing when I create a new account

Comment: I used value.user!.uid and it worked ! Thanks dude

Comment: This should explain those `?` and `!`: https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety